# How do you randomize questions in a quiz game in Java?

Tags: java

I'm making a quiz game for a school project, and I wanted it so that my questions are randomly given, and not in a fixed pattern. I researched on how I can use the randomizer package, but I can't seem to figure out how I can "connect" the randomizer to my questions.

For example:
The number of questions range from 1 to 4, how can I tell Java to randomly pick a question from those set of numbers?

My idea is to make an array and let the randomizer package do the job (refer to the code below), but how to make it so that it chooses from the set of questions I made in the quiz game?

```
        int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3 , 4};

        Random rand = new Random();

        int randomize = rand.nextInt(numbers.length);

        System.out.println(randomize);
```

Comment: Recommend making use of `Collections.shuffle` if you're not restricted to arrays - otherwise you could run into the possibility of randomly selecting a previously asked question

Answer (score 0):

> *"How do you randomize questions in a quiz game in Java? ...
>
>
>
> I wanted it so that my questions are randomly given, and not in a fixed pattern. ..."*

Shuffle the values.

```java
String[] q = {
    "question 1", "question 2", "question 3", "question 4"
};
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(q));
```

Output

```
[question 1, question 3, question 4, question 2]
```

Answer (score -1):

Use:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomQuestionPicker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random random = new Random();

        int minQuestionNumber = 1;
        int maxQuestionNumber = 4;

        int randomQuestionNumber = random.nextInt(maxQuestionNumber - minQuestionNumber + 1) + minQuestionNumber;


        System.out.println("Randomly picked question: " + randomQuestionNumber);
    }
}
```

Refer to the working code sample [here](https://onlinegdb.com/y2_1gqK6c).